# how to close a new tab that has opened by clicking an image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have written a code in html that will open a link in new tab after clicking an image , but the problem is i am unable to close that new window .

I want to know that how to close that new window??

```
<html>
<h1>Click on the image below to open google homepage </h1>

<head>
    <script>
        var x;
        var win = document.links;

        function closeFunc() {
            win[0].close();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="google" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://usercontent1.hubstatic.com/12498898_f520.jpg" alt="image" />
    </a>
    <br> <br>
    <button onclick="closeFunc()"> Close</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can only close windows that were opened with `window.open()`.

Comment: You can't close windows that were opened by clicking on links.

Comment: is there any alternative way to close a new window without using open/close()??

Comment: No, just use Javascript to handle the click event on the image rather than a hyperlink.  In that handler, call window.open() to go to the URL you want.

Comment: window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");  set name ,every time opne windos is same window

Comment: sample like this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close

Comment: i have modified the code as per the suggestions , adding "onclick" then redirecting it to a function. Inside the function, i hv written this

Comment: x = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
 but it is not opening in new window . Instead it is opening in same tab!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just Try This**

```
<html>
<h1>Click on the image below to open google homepage </h1>

<head>
    <script>
        var x;
        var win = document.links;

        function closeFunc() {
            win[0].close();
        }


           function popuponclick()
   {
      my_window = window.open("http://www.google.com",
       "mywindow");

   }

   function closepopup()
   {
      if(false == my_window.closed)
      {
         my_window.close ();
      }
      else
      {
         alert('Window already closed!');
      }
   }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="google" href="javascript: popuponclick()" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://usercontent1.hubstatic.com/12498898_f520.jpg" alt="image" />
    </a>
    <br> <br>
    <button onclick="javascript: closepopup()"> Close</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey what's the difference between javascript:pop() and POP() only??

Comment: If you want to call function from href property of <a> then you have to use ` javascript:pop() ` otherwise you simply use `POP()` in onclick property.

Comment: so, only for href, we should use javascript: ??

Comment: Yes, for href we use.
No need of Thanks just help others.